# how to get the browser name and version you are calling the WebKit in WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Very good, I'm looking for ways that the webkit show me information browser that this rendering and version.Y added to this predetermine the browser you are using, obviously I was looking at pages previously but can not find how to perform this task, WebKit've got it working, I mention this so do not ask me why.
What use are here http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/ as DLL.

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense. What does Webkit have to do with Windows Forms, a desktop technology? If you embed a browser in your WinForms application, don't *you* know already what version you installed?

Comment: Look, I have the webkit running in winforms, and I need a label display browser information that this embedding, that is not see where there is the "no sense"

Comment: The wording of the question is so bad that the question itself doesn't make any sense. One could only guess what you want. The comment doesn't make anything clearer though. *You* added some NuGet package or library that wraps Webkit. You should already know which version it is, or look in that library's documentation. You don't even mention *which* library it is, how do you expect people to know if the wrapper provides *any* information ?

Comment: You know how it works webkit?

Comment: There add what was missing in the question to specify that use

Comment: Then all you have to do is check the library's API reference for the relevant properties. If someone who's never used this library before can find them in a few seconds, someone who already uses it won't have any trouble

Comment: Is that just looking at the properties I can not find it and do not know if I look at the webkit or directly in the browser, but in this area that can not find

Comment: Did you see the properties of the WebKitBrowser class? Did you check the Version and UserAgent properties?

Comment: I have this : LblVersion.Text = webKitBrowser1.Version.ToString(); and this show the Version to WebKit not Chrome o Mozilla,and i need to know or control to webbrowser to open the application.

Comment: I got extract the information I needed, use the user agent of WebKit, but had not specified above by default the WebKit open Mozilla Firefox.      if (webKitBrowser1.UserAgent == "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36")
            {
                toolStripLabel2.Text = "El Navegador utilizado es Google Chrome";
            }
            else
            {
                toolStripLabel2.Text = "Otro Navegador";
            }

Answer (score 0):

I got extract the information I needed, use the user agent of WebKit, but had not specified above by default the WebKit open Mozilla Firefox.` if (webKitBrowser1.UserAgent == "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36") { toolStripLabel2.Text = "El Navegador utilizado es Google Chrome"; } else { toolStripLabel2.Text = "Otro Navegador"; } ``